# Flow over the circle

Tags: plotting, dynamic, vector

I'm trying to plot a vector field over a circle, Particularly the vector field in this plot:

```
VectorPlot[{(Sin[x])^3, 0}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {y, -0.001, 0.001}, 
FrameTicks -> {{\[Pi]/2, \[Pi], 3 \[Pi]/2, 2 \[Pi]}, {-1, 1}},
Epilog ->

Plot[(Sin[x])^3, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
Ticks -> None][[1]], PlotRange -> {{0, 2 \[Pi]}, {-1, 1}}, 
GridLines -> Automatic
]
```

That was my way to plot a vector field over the line. But I want to plot this one-dimensional over a circle.

Comment: The same vector field `{Sin[x]^3, 0}` ? (Note: No parentheses needed around `Sin[x]`. On exactly what circle? (The xy-rectangle in your main plot would only accommodate a very tiny circle, given the constraints on `y` there.)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this?

```
With[{rad = 1, center = {0, 0}},
 Show[
  PolarPlot[{Sin[t]^2, 1}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
   PlotStyle -> Thickness[Medium], PlotRange -> 1.15 rad, 
   PolarGridLines -> Automatic],
  VectorPlot[(Sin[ArcTan[x, y]])^3 {-y, x}/rad, {x, -1.1 rad, 
    1.1 rad}, {y, -1.1 rad, 1.1 rad},
   VectorPoints -> CirclePoints[center, rad, 24]]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the horizontal lengths of the vectors are the y-values of the function for the given x-values; that is `Sin[x]^3`

Using that same approach, the horizontal lengths of the vectors should be the y-values of the points on the circle. For each x-value there are two points on the circle - for the one-dimensional vector field below I picked the positive ones.

Each point on the unit half-circle above the x-axis is of the form {Cos[theta], Sin[theta]} for some angle theta between 0 and pi. The vector field is defined in terms of x and y - so we need the theta for a given x-value: this can be computed using ArcCos[x].

The code below shows a red unit circle with the one-dimensional vector field similar to the one you used.

```
Show[Graphics[{Red, Circle[]}], 
 VectorPlot[{Sin[ArcCos[x]], 0}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -0.001, 0.001}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To only show the positive half-circle you can use

```
Show[ParametricPlot[{Cos[theta], Sin[theta]}, {theta, 0, \[Pi]}, 
 PlotStyle -> Red], 
 VectorPlot[{Sin[ArcCos[x]], 0}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -0.001, 0.001}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For a circle which has a radius other than 1, you may use the code below (which uses radius = 3) which looks pretty much the same, except the scale, which is why the axes are shown.

```
radius = 3; Show[Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, radius]}], 
 VectorPlot[{radius Sin[ArcCos[x/radius]], 0}, {x, -radius, 
   radius}, {y, -0.001, 0.001}], Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]